# Light Absorption by Doubly Ionized Helium

Tags: photons

Doubly ionized Helium is known to absorb light in contracted phase of cepheid stars.  What is the mechanism for photon absorption by an atom that has no electrons to raise to a higher energy level or ionize?

Comment: Perhaps I should have added the question "Where does the absorbed photon energy go? Silliq

Comment: May be in high PT plasma

Comment: Using EM theory of light as opposed to photon theory, energy would be pent pushing plasma electrons or ions around. Possible answer on a macro level.

Comment: Well even free unbound charge can absorb light energy through Commotion scattering. If it is a plasma form than more complicated behavior could occur. Could you put a reference for your question that shows what kind of absorption occurs?

Comment: @KFGauss - I think auto-correct got you there. Although Commotion scattering does sound like it should be a thing. Poor Compton, not in the dictionary...

Comment: It is not clear to me that light absorption has anything to do with the kappa-mechanism. Instead, as the temperature starts to drop in the plasma, electrons recombine with He++, releasing energy and keeping the temperature high. https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/ESSAYS/Evans/evans.html might be a quick read.